# Does .net core sdk 2.1.4 need a project to run ef core scaffold

Tags: .net-core

I have downloaded the .net core sdk 2.1.4. When I run dotnet ef -h I get:

No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"

What do I need to do to get ef core commands as part of dotnet command line.

Sorry I am a newbie at this. Also, I want to run ef core scaffold from command line without a project is that possible?

Comment: use package  manger in visual studio

Comment: thanks that's what I started doing